# Angular NgxTimepicker is getting errors when there is [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular

I experience an error upon page loading
I have this on my template

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="startTime" [ngxTimepicker]="myPicker">
<ngx-material-timepicker #myPicker> </ngx-material-timepicker>
```

startTime initial value is 13:05.

Now the error says `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'time.split') -- ngx-material-timepicker.js:74`

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem but still kinda bothers me that your `ngx-material-timepicker` is not closed `<ngx-material-timepicker #myPicker </ngx-material-timepicker>` You are missing a `>` after `#myPicker`

Comment: oh. thanks for pointing. it's just a typo error on my question. But this is not the solution to my answer.

Comment: problem is, when looking at your code I see nothing wrong with it. Sadly it is not enough information to be able to tell why it fails, this can be solved by debugging or by looking into how `ngxTimepicker` directive works, maybe it doesn't instantly propagate the value of `ngModel` to the timepicker component. I can have a look  on their github and tell you if I see anything suspicious

Comment: I had a look at their github, it seems like it shouldn't be possible to run into this issue. Are you using the most recent version of the timepicker? Also can you add to your question how you initialize `startTime `?

Comment: i'm using the 5.0.0 version. I also thought if maybe it's on initialization of `startTime` but I don't think the problem is in there coz removing the [ngxTimepicker] on input makes the ngModel works fine. Actually, what I'm currently doing is I want to use on the Time Picker instead of <input type="time"> to format the time because that doesn't working on Safari.Therefore I have a working form and I just want to add a time picker for one of its input. And there the problem rises during page loading.

Comment: the fact that the error doesn't pop when you remove the picker doesn't mean that your `startTime` is not null at initialization, because default inputs handle null values just fine, but from I saw in the code of the time picker directive there are also falsy checks everywhere...

Comment: latest version is `5.4.1` though, can you try that? maybe they fixed some bug there

Comment: I installed the latest and it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear! I will post it in my answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments under the question, there was a bug in version `5.0.0` of `ngx-material-timepicker` where it didn't correctly handle null values. Using version `5.4.1` (which is latest at time of writing this answer) must solve the issue.